# Update a print result in a line and update its progressbar at the same time in python

Tags: python, tqdm

I want to update a print result in a first line and update a progressbar in a second line.
I made a python code, but my script prints a text line by line, but not update it in a line.

How can I fix it?

```
from tqdm import *
import time

total_num = 100
bar = tqdm(total=total_num)
bar.set_description('Count Up')

for i in range(total_num):
    bar.update()
    print(f'\r-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+ {i} -+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You can clear the screen by using `subprocess.run("clear")` or `subprocess.run("cls")` on Windows. That's a start.

Comment: Can you share a full code? Where can I use subprocess?

Comment: ```python
from subprocess import run
from sys import platform
def clear():
    run("cls" if platform in {'win32', 'cygwin'} else "clear")
```

Comment: What is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score -1):

You can clear the screen by using python's builtin [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

```py
from subprocess import run
from sys import platform
def clear():
    run("cls" if platform in {'win32', 'cygwin'} else "clear")
```

Comment: It has an error;

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score -1):

your line is not updading because the print function prints a newline character so what you want to do is

```
from tqdm import *
import time
import sys

total_num = 100
bar = tqdm(total=total_num)
bar.set_description('Count Up')

for i in range(total_num):
    bar.update()
    sys.stdout.write(f'\r{i}')
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

but that messes up that output, what i suggest is updating the bar description (this is also on an example on the tqdm github page)

```
from tqdm import *
import time

total_num = 100
bar = tqdm(total=total_num)

for i in range(total_num):
    bar.set_description(f"{i} Count Up")
    bar.update()
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Hello, it's not a solution to update the bar description. The purpose of this ask is to update a long line of text and progressbar at the same time.